# Using dynamic query string to join multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, dynamic-sql

There are thousands of codes that are found within 4 different tables in my database. I have created a temporary table to insert all of the codes and the corresponding table names where that code can be found. As an example I have shown a small piece of the temporary table.

**code** | **table_name**

DA | StatsCanCensus2011_1

DWAPT5L |   StatsCanCensus2011_3

DWAPT5O | StatsCanCensus2011_3

DWDUP | StatsCanCensus2011_3

DWMOVA | StatsCanCensus2011_3

I am trying to write a query where I can dynamically select the codes and join the tables when the codes selected are from different tables. I am able to easily do this for 2 tables however when there are 3 or 4 it doesn't work out.

The following will give the result I need for when 2 tables need to be joined:

```
declare @code nvarchar(15), @tblname nvarchar(30), @strSQL nvarchar(max), @strWhere nvarchar(max)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
select  code, table_name from tmpVarList2

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @code,   @tblname
set @strSQL='select'
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       print @code + @tblname
       set @strSQL=@strSQL + ' ' +  @code + ','
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @code,   @tblname   
END   

set @strSQL=left(@strSQL, len(@strSQL)-1)

print @strSQL
CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor


set @strSQL=@strSQL + ' from'
set @strWhere=' where '
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
select  distinct  table_name from tmpVarList2

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tblname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       print @code + @tblname
       set @strSQL=@strSQL + ' ' +  @tblname + ','
       set @strWhere=@strWhere + @tblname + '.da=' 
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tblname   
END   

set @strSQL=left(@strSQL, len(@strSQL)-1) 
set @strWhere=left(@strWhere, len(@strWhere)-1) 
set @strSQL=@strSQL + @strWhere


SELECT @strSQL

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

**Result:**

```
select DA, DWAPT5L, DWAPT5O, DWDUP, DWMOVA 
from StatsCanCensus2011_1, StatsCanCensus2011_3 
where StatsCanCensus2011_1.da=StatsCanCensus2011_3.da
```

**Example of result when there are 3 tables joined:**

```
select DA, DWAPT5L, FMCLNOCH,FMCPINTO, FMCPSZAV, FMCPTIAV, FMCPTIME, FMHHTOT 
from StatsCanCensus2011_1, StatsCanCensus2011_3, StatsCanNHS2011_4 
where StatsCanCensus2011_1.da=StatsCanCensus2011_3.da=StatsCanNHS2011_4.da
```

Comment: I recommend you re-write to use `JOIN ... ON` instead of separating tables with commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a cursor to assemble and execute dynamic sql queries is ambitious, but it means the execution path can never be cached. Also If these are large tables (as census data tends to be) you could have some real challenges optimizing. With the standard DBA nags out of the way, it's actually a really amusing idea because it sounds awful but isn't actually so bad (since the cursor never touches data).

I think you are on the correct approach, but you are trying to make each cursor do too much. There are three parts to your desired query, a select statement with a list of columns, a from statement with a list of joined tables, and a where statement that contains the logic for joining those tables (implicitly joining them instead of explicitly doing so). So why not three cursors, each focusing on a specific area. It allows each cursor to be much simpler to construct, and then you can combine the final results.

```
declare @select_Code varchar(max)
declare @Select_column varchar(max)
declare @selectloop int
declare @From_Code varchar(max)
declare @From_Column varchar(max)
declare @FromLoop int
declare @Where_Code Varchar(max)

create table #temp (columnname varchar(128), tablename Varchar(128))

insert into #temp
select 'ColumnA', 'TableA'
union
select 'Columnb', 'TableB'
union
select 'Columnc', 'TableC'

--drop table #temp

set @select_Code = 'Select '
set @selectloop = 0

declare select_cursor cursor for
  select columnname from #temp

Open select_cursor

fetch next from select_cursor 
into @Select_column


while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
set @select_Code = @select_Code + (select case when @selectloop > 0 then ', ' else '' end as CommaOrNot) + @Select_column 
set @selectloop = @selectloop + 1

fetch next from select_cursor into @Select_column
end
close select_cursor
deallocate select_cursor

set @From_Code = ' From '
set @FromLoop = 0

declare From_cursor cursor for
  select tablename from #temp

Open From_cursor

fetch next from From_cursor
into @from_column


while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
set @From_Code = @From_Code + (select case when @FromLoop > 0 then ', ' else '' end as CommaOrNot) + @from_column
set @FromLoop = @FromLoop + 1

fetch next from From_cursor into @from_column
end
close From_cursor
deallocate From_cursor

select @select_Code + @From_Code
```

I'll let you do the where clause since I'm not sure if you are daisy chaining them, or if they all join back to the first table, whichever it is It follows the same pattern, you'll just need to update the case statement to something like;

```
case when @whereloop > 0 and @whereloop % 2 = 0 then ' and '
     when @whereloop > 0 and @whereloop % 2 = 1 then ' = '
     else '' end as EqualsOrNewJoin
```

For the select and from statements I use the loop number to determine if I need to add commas before the concat between the existing code and the new section. For the where clause it's a bit trickier, it needs to be where x = y and y = z. So I use mod to get the remainder of the loop number to determine if the loop is odd or even once we are past the first (loop 0). if it's odd (loop 1 which is the second entry) I know that there should be an = sign between them eg: Loop0 = loop1. If it's even I know we are statring a new where condition so I need to use and. Anyway hope this helps, and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it has helped out a lot. I am working through a few kinks and will let you know how it goes! Simplifying things by splitting up each task into a different cursor make it so much easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following commands:

```
CREATE Temp Table Adv_Search_Trails(Parameter_Name Text, Parameter_Value Text,Condition Text,Table_Name Text )
```

---

```
INSERT INTO Adv_Search_Trails
```

---

```
SELECT 'trial_therapeutic_area_id','5','AND','trial_ta_filterview'     
UNION ALL SELECT 'Primary_Drug','6','AND','trial_drugid_filterview' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'collaborator_id','7','AND','trial_status_filterview' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'maximum_age','8','OR','trial_patient_filterview'
UNION ALL SELECT 'designkeyword_id','9','OR','trial_key_filterview'
```

---

```
DECLARE @select_Code NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @Select_column VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @selectloop INT
DECLARE @From_Code VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @From_Column VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @FromLoop INT
```

---

```
SET @select_Code = ' where '
SET @selectloop = 0
```

---

```
DECLARE select_cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT Parameter_Name
FROM Adv_Search_Trails
```

---

```
OPEN select_cursor
```

---

```
FETCH NEXT
FROM select_cursor
INTO @Select_column
```

---

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @select_Code = @select_Code + (
        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN @selectloop > 0
                THEN (
                        SELECT Condition
                        FROM Adv_Search_Trails
                        WHERE Parameter_Name = @Select_column
                     )
                ELSE ''
                END AS CommaOrNot
        ) + ' ' + @Select_column + ' = ' + (
            SELECT Parameter_Value
            FROM Adv_Search_Trails
            WHERE Parameter_Name = @Select_column
        ) + '  '
    SET @selectloop = @selectloop + 1

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM select_cursor
    INTO @Select_column
END
```

---

```
CLOSE select_cursor
```

---

```
DEALLOCATE select_cursor
```

---

```
SET @From_Code = ' from '
SET @FromLoop = 0
```

---

```
DECLARE From_cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT Table_Name
FROM Adv_Search_Trails
```

---

```
OPEN From_cursor
```

---

```
FETCH NEXT
FROM From_cursor
INTO @from_column
```

---

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @From_Code = @From_Code + (
        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN @FromLoop > 0
                THEN ' INNER JOIN ' + @from_column+ ' ON ' + (SELECT TOP 1 table_name from Adv_Search_Trails)+'.ID '+' = ' +@from_column +'.ID'
            ELSE @from_column
                END AS CommaOrNot
        ) 
    SET @FromLoop = @FromLoop + 1

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM From_cursor
    INTO @from_column
END
```

---

```
CLOSE From_cursor
```

---

```
DEALLOCATE From_cursor
```

---

```
SELECT 'select ' +@from_column+'.ID '+ @From_Code  + @select_Code
```

Comment: Hope, it will help to join multiple tables dynamically